# Is it possible to make python calplot interactive (clickable)?

Tags: python, calendar, heatmap, interactive

after browsing the existing topics for a while on StackOverflow it's high time for me to write my first post.

I was asked at work to prepare an interactive calendar-like visualization of data availability for the project's website. I am not a programmer and have only basic skills in Python so it's kinda challenging.

I came across python calplot library and it works perfectly fine - each day from data range is coloured according to a color-scale (at this point only binary: 0 - no data, 1 - there is data) but how can I make this visualisation more interactive?

The final idea is to put this calendar view to a website, where users would be able to click on a square (picked day) and as a result, be directed to the appropriate data file in our database.

I just worked on sample .txt file with a structure as follows: date, data availability for given day, file name in database. Here's the code and output:

```
[all_days = pd.date_range(min(df\['date'\]), max(df\['date'\]), freq='D')
events = df\[ \['date', 'available'\] \].set_index('date').squeeze()
calplot.calplot(events, cmap = 'binary', colorbar = False);
```

[Code output - calplot visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2OXG.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is there an error or incorrect output?

Comment: Hey, I am wondering, how to make the date squares interactive, So that the final user could download the file containing data from the selected day after clicking it. Is it even possible to do that in calplot?

Comment: What is your current code doing?

Comment: The output is provided in the link at the end of my post. I wasn't able to embed image inside the post. It's just a plot basically. I want to make it "clickable".